# Polymorphism for return type in dotnet REST API

Tags: c#, json, rest, .net-core

In context of a dotnet core REST api, I want to return a 'light' version of objects when listing them to avoid a lot of unacessary data. I try to use polymorphism to do so :

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class Student : Person
{
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet("testList")]
public List<Person> getPersons()
{
  List<Person> testList = new List<Person>();
  testList.Add(new Student() { FirstName = "Kevin", LastName = "Smith", Age = 99 });
  return testList;
}

[HttpGet("test")]
public Student getStudent()
{
  return new Student() { FirstName = "Kevin", LastName = "Smith", Age = 99 };
}
```

When I call `/testList`, I got the following json :

```
[
  {
    "age": 99,
    "firstName": "Kevin",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  }
]
```

I was expecting return to not contain `age` parameter due to return type, but it's not the case.
Is there a way to get a 'light version' only for the listing method ?

Thank you,

Comment: Any solution like this will soon become redundant, unmaintainable and create a lot of noise in a large system, I would suggest creating dedicated DTO's (light poco classes) and map to them.

Comment: But you could create a cunstructor Person(Person p) and add only Persons to the List

Comment: Can you not just create a light version of the student object, which only contains name?

Comment: Create 2 classes without inheritance was my backup option. Just wondering if something like in the topic can be achieve.

Comment: You can use Anonymous Type objects and also you can use inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) to return only the information you want. Use it like this:

```
[HttpGet("testList")]
public List<PersonDto> getPersons()
{
  List<Person> testList = new List<Person>(); // ... fetch records from data source

  return testList.Select(e => new PersonDto() { // PersonDto contains only props you need
    FirstName = e.FirstName,
    LastName = e.LastName
  });
}
```

Comment: This solution was my backup plan. This confirms my intention to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Please note that this needs a lot of mapping code between Business Objects and DTOs. Depending on the complexity of your api it is worth to create a converter to automatically copy properties from one to another object, you can also consider to use libs like AutoMapper

Answer (score 1):

When we use inheritance, we must remember that the child object can be replaced by the parent object, and you have done exactly the same here, and when it becomes to json, the real type of objects is considered, not their abstract type.
You can return parent object like this:

```
public static List<Person> getPersons()
{
  List<Person> testList = new List<Person>();
  testList.Add(new Student() { FirstName = "Kevin", LastName = "Smith", Age = 99 });
  return testList.Select(e=> new Person() {FirstName=e.FirstName,LastName=e.LastName}).ToList();
}
```

And i think good idea is using Dto's,As our friend @TWP mentioned above.